# custom notification layout doesn't cover the whole width

Tags: android, android-layout

i am trying to create a custom layout of NotificationManager , here is my layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layoutnotification"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="3dp"

    android:background="@color/btn_bg_blue">
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_height= "50dp"
        android:layout_width= "50dp"

         />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/image"
        style="@style/NotificationTitle" />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/image"
        android:layout_below="@id/title"
        style="@style/NotificationText" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

currently the notification appears as follow , but the problem is the notification layout doesn't cover the whole width (on right side) even though i have set `layout_width to fill_parent` so i want the blue color covers the whole width.

[image]

Comment: is this behavior on Emulator or custom roms?

Comment: i have tried it on emulator and on my HTC cell phone too , by the way above screen shot is from emulator

Comment: did you ever figure it out? I am having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `android:padding="3dp"`.  It's pushing the background color 3 pixels inward.  If you need those three pixels, replace it with `android:layout_marginRight="3dp"`.

Comment: i have tried removing all the elements except the main layout but no luck

Answer (score 0):

If you remove all the paddings and margins in your layout elements, i guess there's still possibility that you can see this gap. I've noticed this sometimes on my HTC Desire too. However, I've also noticed that if I highlight and then unhighlight the event with trackball (available in Desire) or with navigation keys, the gap suddenly goes away. I can't tell you why this behavior is, but it is something I've experienced in notification bar too.

Just highlight and then unhighlight your notification and see if there's any difference.

Answer (score 0):

I saw many custom notification layouts, some they solve this problem by using transparent background, some they do the same gap in the left by padding to make it center. I don't believe there is a solution for it. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same problem but now its fixed. Just check your app on real device of android 2.3.
good luck :)